# Biking tour in Russia

Tags: health, safety, russia, bicycles

I am from Turkey and planning a bike tour in Russia and in Ukraine. I'll ride from Sochi to Yalta by using the Sochi - Anapa - Rostov on Don - Mariupol - Yalta destination. Is this route secure and comfortable for biking and tent camping?

Comment: Welcome to the site. As per the [faq], we usually try for one question per post, and to not have ones that can be subjectively answered (eg "is it reasonable?").  Could you please edit your post and ask new questions if need be - so that you have just one question per post.  Otherwise it's going to risk being closed, which would be a shame on an interesting question like this!

Comment: I am new and I didn't know the rules. I'm sorry... I have never been abroad before and I'm wondering everything. I meant, if the route is secure and comfortable for bikers and campers... I used the "reasonable" word for this question. I'll change my question.
Thanks

Comment: No worries, that's why I pointed out the [faq] for you :) You've come to the right place for travel questions, although you may also consider [The Great Outdoors](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/) for camping-type questions.

Comment: The bike tour is designed for international cyclists, and it will introduce you to the real Russia! Bicycling is an ideal way to explore this fascinating country.

Comment: If you have questions about specifically about riding, you can stop by the [Bicycles site](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/), where we have asked and answered many [questions about touring](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touring).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This route is just perfect for traveling by bike - a great climate, beautiful nature, good roads, recreational areas .... moreover, in this region there are several biker clubs that can help you in arranging the trip and laying of the optimal route. you can feel free to contact them for help. here are some of them: http://custommoto.com.ua/articles/20/, http://www.irbit.info/biker/adress.фп, http://nightwolves.info/ru/contacts